# Permission denied when trying to create message queue using POSIX Message Queues

Tags: c, posix, ipc

I am creating a message queue with the following snippet by following [The Linux Programming Interface](http://man7.org/tlpi/).

```
if((mq_open("/my_message_queue", O_CREAT, O_RDWR, NULL)) == -1) {
    perror("mq creation failed");
}
```

Running this snippet I get an error: "permission denied". I wanted to check and see if I had created the queue previously and not destroyed it, so I used ipcs. However, ipcs does not show any active message queues. I have never used the POSIX IPC libraries in my development environment before (Ubuntu 18.04). Is some set up I must do to allow my user process to create a message queue? Am I using the API incorrectly?

Comment: Your msgqueue limit is probably set to 0.  Look into `ulimit` and `limits.conf`.

Comment: Try running `ulimit -q` from the terminal and see what it outputs.

Comment: ulimit -q returns 819200

Comment: Oh!  `"/my_message_queue"`.  You're trying to create a msgqueue in the root directory, which you shouldn't have write permission on.

Comment: Okay, thanks for letting me know, I will change that

Comment: In what directory can I crate message queues on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Try just putting it in the working directory.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons POSIX message queues (`mq_open()`) names are allowed to start with a `/`, and any other use of a `/` character is implementation-defined.  Assuming Linux, only the leading `/` character is allowed in the name passed to `mq_open()`.

Comment: You need more than just `O_CREAT` in the second argument. See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mq_open.3.html

Answer (score 2):

From [the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mq_open.3.html):

> The oflag argument specifies flags that control the operation of the call.  (Definitions of the flags values can be obtained by including `<fcntl.h>`.)  Exactly one of the following must be specified in oflag:
>
> O_RDONLY Open the queue to receive messages only.
>
> O_WRONLY Open the queue to send messages only.
>
> O_RDWR Open the queue to both send and receive messages.

You have none of those three values in your code. Or rather you do, but it's in the `mode` argument, not the `oflag` one, where the corresponding number has a completely different meaning. That third argument is the filesystem permission bits used when creating the queue (just like the third argument to `open()` when creating a new file), not the mode the queue is opened in.

Comment: But note that `O_RDONLY` is defined as `0`. (but this *is* the only answer that's mostly right, I think)

Comment: @o12c That's an implementation detail that shouldn't be relied on. I'm pretty sure the actual values of those macros aren't set by the relevant standards.

Answer (score 0):

*EACCES: The queue exists, but the caller does  not  have  permission  to
              open it in the specified mode.*

ipcs won't show you queues that you can't read.  That it doesn't show you the queue is consistent with mq_open returning a permission error.

TLPI describes **mount -t mqueue** to a directory of your choosing.  You can then use **ls**(1) on that directory to see the queues, and even interrogate the queues' states by reading the "files" in that directory.

My guess is the queue exists and belongs to root....

Comment: Can I view queues that belong to the root by another method? I did not see mount -t mqueue in chapter 52, maybe I missed it.

Comment: you are right the queue exists and belongs to root. It is under /dev/mqueue but does not show up under ipcs

Answer (score 0):

[POSIX states](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mq_open.html) :

> ... The name argument conforms to the construction rules for a pathname, except that the interpretation of `<slash>` characters other than the leading `<slash>` character in name is implementation-defined ...

On Linux, the name `/my/message_queue` is incorrect. Linux requires the name to start with `/`, but it can contain no other `/` characters.

Per the [Linux `mq_overview.7` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html):

> Message queues are created and opened using `mq_open(3)`; this function
>          returns a message queue descriptor (`mqd_t`), which is used to refer to
>          the open message queue in later calls.  Each message queue is
>          identified by a name of the form `/somename`; that is, a null-
>          terminated string of up to `NAME_MAX` (i.e., 255) characters consisting
>          of an initial slash, followed by one or more characters, **none of
>          which are slashes.**

Comment: my name is "/my_message_queue" which follows the naming rules, I think.