# How can I create a POSIX shared message queue without it created as root access only?

Tags: c, posix, ipc, ubuntu-18.04

I am creating a message queue using the POSIX mqueue API:

```
    mq_open("/myqueue", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, O_WRONLY, NULL)
```

I also mount the directory for the message queue objects:

```
su
mkdir /dev/mqueue
mount -t mqueue none /dev/mqueue
exit
```

When I run my program, the message queue appears in /dev/mqueue with permissions:

```
---------x
```

I cannot interact with this message queue, and it does not show up with the ipcs command.

How can I create a POSIX message queue to be used by a user-level application in Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permission denied when trying to create message queue using POSIX Message Queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58477463/permission-denied-when-trying-to-create-message-queue-using-posix-message-queues)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your arguments to the function are wrong. You're passing `O_WRONLY` as the *mode*, but it's a flag, just like the other `O_`*. Instead you should do:

```
mq_open("/myqueue", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0600, NULL);
```

or some other file access mode that you want (`0600` = `rw-------`).